# Load event not firing in iframe while loading pdf in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, onload-event

This is my HTML :-

```
<iframe src="Dyanamicallygeneratedpath" id="iPrintform" name="iPrintform"  class="iframeDisable" scrolling="auto" height="600" width="650" style="display:block;"></iframe>
```

Jquery :-

1st Attempt :-

```
var iFrame = $('#iPrintform');
iFrame.bind('load', function () { //binds the event
alert('iFrame Reloaded');
});
```

2nd Attempt:-

```
$("#iPrintform").on("load", function () {
alert("Iframe loaded");
});
```

I tried binding load event, onready event to iframe, nothing is working for chrome.

Comment: Try using live instead of bind

Comment: Live is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing below code.

```
var iframeID = $('#iPrintform').contents();
    iframeID.find("addevents").click(function(){
       alert("working");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait until iframe is loaded, then bind via the iframe's contentWindow.document

```
 var xiframe = $('iframe')[0];
 iframe.onload = function(){
   // log("iframe loaded");
   $(xiframe.contentWindow.document)
    .bind(function(){ ... });
    $(xiframe.contentWindow.body).addClass('..');
    };
```

Comment: No luck! Event is not getting bound to iframe.